# What are URL required to Unblock Firewall in Corporate network for accessing for Google text to speech API?

Tags: java, google-api, google-text-to-speech

Current google Text to speech My code in java working perfectly but when uploaded to server that showing Error which is below code, as i know server is too secure so may be that needs to unblock from firewall but i could't find which are accessing in background.

I have tried proxy setup in environment variable but it's not working.

```java
try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()) {
        // Set the text input to be synthesized
        SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder()
              .setText(strText)
              .build();

        VoiceSelectionParams voice = VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder()
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
            .build();

            // Select the type of audio file you want returned
            AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.newBuilder()
            .setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3)
            .build();

        // Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected voice parameters and
        // audio file type
        SynthesizeSpeechResponse syntehsizeResponse = textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice,
            audioConfig);   

        // Get the audio contents from the response
        ByteString audioContents = syntehsizeResponse.getAudioContent();


Error-----------------------------------------------------------------

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE 
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.shutdownWithError(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:897)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a URL that needs unblocking? It's possible that your runtime is linked against a version of OpenSSL that is too old. The error message indicates an SSLv3 handshake failure, but SSLv3 is quite old and no longer supported by most websites on the Internet.

Comment: @DanielPryden Really I am not sure but that thing is already giving me problem, but are sure about this error i can share full Error log if you have some idea about this?

Comment: For starters, what is the version of the Java runtime, and specifically of OpenSSL, on this "secure" server? I put "secure" in quotes because any server that is using a version of the OpenSSL library that is vulnerable to the POODLE attack is definitely not secure any more.

Comment: @DanielPryden Got Solution there is "speech.googleapis.com" URL which need to clear by firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

speech.googleapis.com is basic link which is required to clear in firewall.